# jquery datatables export to excel

Tags: jquery, datatables

i'm trying to use TableTools to export the datatable (example) into excel or csv , I prefer Excel. but with this code below it's not even show me the icons (export/print/csv/..) I made several changes but nothing helped  . .
what am I doing wrong? what am I missing?
there is any example of how to implement it? 
I also did it exactly as they do in the official site and it's still not working.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/jquery.dataTables.css">

<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
```

```
<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

```js
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "server_processing_harigot.php",
   data: {
     str: str,
     hotel_id: hotel_id
   },
   cache: false,
   success: function(result) {
     data = JSON.parse(result);
     $.each(data, function(index, data) {
       //!!!--Here is the main catch------>fnAddData
       $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData([
         data.phone_number,
         data.name,
         data.client_id,
         data.employee

       ]);

     });

   }

 });
 $('#example').dataTable({
   "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
   "oTableTools": {
     "sSwfPath": "swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
   }
 });
```

```html
<table width="100%" id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0">
  <caption><strong> example </strong>
  </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>phone_number</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>client_id</th>
      <th>employee</th>


    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tablebody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the reference for `dataTables.tableTools.js` and
`dataTables.tableTools.css`.

See [here](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/examples/simple.html) for examples

EDIT: **This feature has now moved over to combination of using Buttons and Select extensions**.
See [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/).

Comment: Thanks alot ! i watched the example .. i missed the dataTables.tableTools.js  and the swf path.

Comment: what should be the swf path, where can i get the swf file